# Toggle timer function

Tags: timers

I want to write a function that starts a timer if timer does not exists or stop it if that one exists. I mean something like:

```
(defun toggle-mytimer () 
  (interactive)

  (if (timerp TIMER_NAME)
      (cancel TIMER_NAME)
    ;; else
    (run-with-timer 5 5 'princ "Ciao"))
  )
```

The `run-with-timer` docstring says:

`This function returns a timer object which you can use in ‘cancel-timer’`

but I'm not able to find the object name that would be `TIMER_NAME` in my function. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to keep the timer object in a global variable or closure.

Take global variable for example:

```
(defvar my/timer nil)

(defun toggle-mytimer () 
  (interactive)
  (if (not (timerp my/timer))
      (setq my/timer (run-with-timer 5 5 'princ "Ciao"))
    (cancel-timer my/timer)
    (setq my/timer nil)))
```

Comment: Welcome! It works. I upvoted your anwer but I'll wait for other hints before mark it as accepted.

Comment: Glad I could help :)